# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative name found matching IP address even when using a FQDN

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to send an HTTPS request to `precision.epayworldwide.com` from my Java application.

This is the code I am using:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://precision.epayworldwide.com/up-interface");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String responseLine = reader.readLine();

while (responseLine != null)
{
    System.out.printf("%s\n", responseLine);
    responseLine = reader.readLine();
}
```

and this is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: certificate_unknown(46)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient$1.notifyServerCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.processServerCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleServerCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative name found matching IP address 195.145.98.203
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.HostnameUtil.checkHostname(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkEndpointID(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkEndpointID(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkExtendedTrust(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

I have correctly imported the TLS certificate of that hostname:

```
Owner: C=GB,L=Billericay,O=Epay Limited,CN=*.epayworldwide.com
Issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
Serial number: 97cc7ab5601ca15b1e65530f3a3e8a3
Valid from: Mon Oct 10 02:00:00 CEST 2022 until: Sun Nov 05 00:59:59 CET 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  AF:C4:FA:F6:A2:99:D8:C3:C3:9A:1D:B7:A4:6D:D7:21
         SHA1: 4D:55:B9:2B:69:67:2E:AA:2A:B4:3B:B6:D1:BC:35:77:B0:FD:50:A0
         SHA256: 96:AF:91:70:80:F6:F1:9E:30:18:CC:97:53:10:B4:7E:B2:CC:37:31:77:CB:C1:E1:1C:14:BC:CF:19:08:04:3B
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256WITHRSA
         Version: 3
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

I don't understand why the code is throwing that exception. I have searched here on StackOverflow and I have found similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540289/how-to-fix-the-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185157/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157861/java-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative-names-matching-ip-address)), but these people used an IP address to connect to the server, instead of an FQDN.

I do not control the server so I can't change the certificate in any way.

Is there something I can do client-side without disabling the hostname verification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't want to change the code, I digged in the BouncyCastle's Githb issue tracker and I found this JVM property:

> From v1.70 if you want to use option 1 please prefer
> **`-Dorg.bouncycastle.jsse.client.assumeOriginalHostName=true`**
> instead of
> `-Djdk.tls.trustNameService=true`

(see [issue 460](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/460) and linked issues for more references)

So I have added this property to my JVM arg list and now the TLS handshake to `precision.epayworldwide.com` works.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this bug report](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/660) HttpURLConnection will only use SNI with SunJSSE as JSSE provider but not with others like BouncyCastle - which you are using. That's why you see that it tries to check the certificate against the IP address instead of the FQDN:

> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative name found matching IP address 195.145.98.203

Answer (score 1):

This is an underlying issue with HttpsURLConnection not working properly with third-party JSSE implementations.

Since you are opening the URL directly (rather than via some framework that's hard to modify) the simplest solution is probably to use the BCJSSE utility class `org.bouncycastle.jsse.util.URLConnectionUtil`:

```
new URLConnectionUtil().openConnection(url)
```

You can also pass a specific SSLSocketFactory to URLConnectionUtil constructor if BCJSSE is not configured as the default provider.

For background on the underlying problem refer to various issues:

- https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/460
- https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/660
- https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/709
- https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/1331